# SQL DEFAULT VALUE

Tags: sql

I would like to set a default value to a variable

```
SELECT ID, VALUE
FROM TABLE
```

Now I would like that value to have a default value of 0 for every ID. What can I do?

Comment: Is your Caps-Lock broken or is there another reason you are shouting at us?

Comment: can you be a bit more specfic: it's clear from the answers so far that we are having to guess a bit as to what your requirements are!

Comment: Is this what you want... display ID and Value from a table. When Value is null, display 0, otherwise display value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, 0 as value_default from myTable
```

so you have an initial default value assigned against a named column (the value of which you can change).

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking how to specify a default value in the select:

```
SELECT ID, 0 as VALUE FROM TABLE
```

Or do you want to have the underlying table column have a default value?

Comment: i want to set value of a variable to 0

Comment: @MOHIT BANSAL: won't the `update table set value = 0` would suffice?  why need the word DEFAULT there?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want a default value for when the column is null then you can use the NVL function (at least in oracle), e.g.

```
SELECT NVL(thecol, 0) FROM thetable;
```

Comment: `NVL` only works with Oracle, use `COALESCE` to work with other DBs too.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, IFNULL(VALUE,0) as Value
FROM MyTable
```

This will select ID, and Value. If value is null it will display 0